# errors running sh script

Tags: linux, bash

I keep getting these errors running my script and i just cannot work it out...

the error that keeps coming up is;

rm: cannot remove ~/my-documents/article:': Is a directory. The directory its referring to is $2...here is my script.

```
#! /bin/sh

SRC=$1
DES=$2

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
echo "1. Please enter the source directory"
echo "2. Please enter the destination directory"
echo "thankyou"
exit
fi


if [ ! -d $1 ]; then
echo "$1 is not a directory please enter a valid directory"
echo "thankyou"
exit
fi
#gives the user a error warning the source directory is invalid


if [ -d $2 ]; then
echo "output directory exists"
else
echo "Output directory does not exist, creating directory"
mkdir $2
fi
#creates the destination directory if one doesn't exist


IFILE=$GETFILES;
FINDFILE=$FINDFILE;


 find $1 -name "*.doc" > FINDFILE
 find $1 -name "*.pdf" > FINDFILE
 find $1 -name "*.PDF" > FINDFILE
 #finds doc, pdf & PDF files and sends data to findfile.

 while read -r line;
 do
 cp $line $2
 done < FINDFILE
 #files read and copied to destination directory

 IFILE=$2/$GETFILES;
 ls -R $1 | egrep -i ".doc | .pdf" > IFILE;

 LCOUNT=0
 DIFFCOUNT=0
 FOUND=0
 ARCHIVE=1
 BASE="${line%.*}"
 EXTENSION="${line##*.}"

COUNT=$COUNT;

ls $2 | grep ${line%%.*} \; | wc -l 

if [[ $COUNT -eq 0 ]];
then
cp $1/$line $2;
else
echo "there is already a file in the output so need to compare"
COMP=$2/$line
fi

while [[ $FOUND -eq 0 ]] && [[ $LCOUNT -lt $COUNT ]]; 
do
echo "diffcount is $DIFFCOUNT"

###compares the file from the input directory to the file in 
###the output directory 

if [ $DIFFCOUNT -eq 0 ];
then
echo "file has already been archived no action required"
FOUND=$FOUND [ $FOUND+1 ]
else
LCOUNT=$LCOUNT [ $LCOUNT+1 ]
COMP="OUT"/"$BASE"_"$LCOUNT"."$EXTENSION"
echo "line count for next compare is $LCOUNT"
echo "get the next file to compare"
echo "the comparison file is now $COMP"
fi
    if [ $LCOUNT -ne $COUNT ]; then
    ARCHIVE=$ [ $ARCHIVE+1 ]
    else
    ARCHIVE=0
    fi

    if [ $ARCHIVE -eq 0 ];
    then
    NEWOUT="OUT"/"$BASE"_"$LCOUNT"."$EXTENSION";
    echo "newfile name is $NEWOUT"
    cp $1/$LINE $NEWOUT
    fi

done < $IFILE
rm $IFILE

OFILE=$2/DOCFILES;
ls $2 | grep ".doc" > $OFILE;

while read -r line;
do

BASE=${line%.*}
EXTENSION=${line##*.}
NEWEXTENSION=".pdf"
SEARCHFILE=$BASE$NEWEXTENSION

find $2 -name "$SEARCHFILE" -exec {} \;
done < $OFILE
rm $OFILE

### this will then remove any duplicate files so only 
### individual .doc .pdf files will exist
```

Comment: What is `$GETFILES`? Where does it get a value from? (Add `set -x` to the top of your script to see what is actually being run and you should see your problem.)

Answer (score 2):

a plain call to `rm` can only remove *files*, not *directories*.

```
$ touch /tmp/myfile
$ rm /tmp/myfile

$ mkdir /tmp/mydir
$ rm /tmp/mydir
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/mydir/’: Is a directory
```

You can remove *directories* by specifying the `-d` (to delete *empty* directories) or the `-r` (to delete directories and content recursively) flag:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/mydir
$ rm -r /tmp/mydir
$
```

this is well described in `man rm`.

apart from that, you seem to ignore quoting:

```
 $ rm $OFILE
```

might break badly if the value of `OFILE` contains spaces, use *quotes* instead:

```
 $ rm "${OFILE}"
```

and [never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
 ls $2 | grep ".doc" > $OFILE
```

(e.g. if your "$2" is actually "/home/foo/my.doc.files/" it will put all files in this directory into  $OFILE).

and then you iterate over the contents of this file?

instead, just use loop with file-globbing:

```
 for o in "${2}"/*.doc
 do
   ## loop code in here
 done
```

or just do the filtering with `find` (and don't forget to call an *executable* with `-exex`):

```
 find "$2" -name "$SEARCHFILE" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec convertfile \{\} \;
```